# Обновление primary key при обновлении записи MySQL

Tags: mysql

Возможно ли выполнить запрос который обновит не только данные в записи таблицы, но и uid(primary key) записи на новый(последний) без риска получить дубликат ключа?
Сейчас на ум приходит только вариант просто удалять запись и создавать insert'ом новую с такими же данными, но уже новым uid.

Comment: Если у Вас на регулярной основе возникает потребность изменять Primary Key у записи, то, с большой долей вероятности, Вы делаете что-то не так. :)

Comment: @Yaant возможно :) суть такова, что данные хочется подгружать без limit 100,30 , но метод where uid > x limit 30 не могу использовать по причине, что помимо столбца uid есть еще timepub которое хранит время публикации записи, и оно обновляется. Таким образом при order by timepub,uid не получается проделать такой трюк с where uid > x так как порядок uid нарушается в записях которые с новым timepub. В итоге в голову пришло только одно - обновление timepub вместе с uid, таки образом будет порядок и обновленная запись будет уже как новая запись в бд :)

Comment: Я бы сделал два поля - время публикации, и время последнего редактирования (изначально равное времени публикации), и сортировал бы по этим двум полям.

Comment: @SergPolyakov Тогда запоминайте не uid записи, которую показали последней, а дату (tX) и uid (uX). Для поиска следующего блока записей дополняете uX нулями слева, скажем до 12 символов, объединяете и делаете выборку `where date >= dX and concat(timepub, lpad(uid, 12, '0')) > concat(tX, lpad(uX, 12, '0')) order by timepub, uid limit ...` (первое условие нужно что бы был быстрый поиск при наличии индекса по полю с датой).

Comment: А про модификацию первичного ключа забудьте как про страшный сон, иначе эти самые сны станут постоянными. Вы не сможете привесить к публикации например теги или посчитать показы/голоса и и т.п. потому что не сможете сослаться на запись из других таблиц. Если что то пойдет не так, даже имея логи всех изменений отследить что во что превратилось будет не реально. так же при модификации/удалении записи вы никогда не сможете быть уверены, что ее id еще не изменился за время редактирования и вы никогда не найдете что же вы хотели поменять

Comment: @Mike Вы сделали мой день)) это гениально)) я целый день думал как обойтись без обновление uid, потому что понимал что с этим будет геморрой, как Вы и говорили приходилось бы постоянно менять все связи.

Comment: @Mike Огромное спасибо!!)

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо @Mike за ответ!

Запоминаем у последней записи выведенной на экран два поля uid(далее uX) и время публикации(далее tX)

```
where timepub <= tX and concat(timepub, lpad(uid, 12, '0')) < concat(tX, lpad(uX, 12, '0')) order by timepub DESC,uid DESC limit 30
```